# DataGridView custom row layout

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to create two Rows in one **DataGridView** Row. One for controls and one for **Image** (below). **Image** needs to be clickable so it has to fire event which opens new **Form** with zoomed **Image**. There are couple other issues like no **Numeric** Control for **DGV**. Has anybody idea how to handle with it?

[image]

Comment: One issue solved. To insert NumericUpDown control into cell I used this three .cs files: http://code.google.com/p/laboratorios-de-informatica-4-etapa3/source/browse/trunk/?r=144#trunk%2FDataGridViewNumericUpDownElements But I still don't know how to change Cells positions for custom layout.